# This app has been disabled in Communication between Fragments in ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have tried an example of a Communication between Fragments in ViewPager and the app working successfully  , this is the link " [link](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2012/09/life-cycle-of-fragments-in-viewpager.html) "
But when I change the theme for this app, this problem show (Problem "This app has been disabled") What do I do?
this is my Android Manifest:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="androidviewpager.exercise.com.androidviewpager"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" android:targetSdkVersion="11" />
    <application
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity
            android:name=".AndroidViewPager"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Note:
I mean changing the theme Add this theme:

```
<Style name = "AppColor" parent = "Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
         <! - Customize your theme here. ->
         <Item name = "colorPrimary"> @ color / colorPrimary </ item>
         <Item name = "colorPrimaryDark"> @ color / colorPrimaryDark </ item>
         <Item name = "colorAccent"> @ color / colorAccent </ item>
     </ Style>
```

Through the Android Manifest the application tells "This app has been disabled", you can see the application form through the link at the top>
Please help me!

Comment: What do you mean change the theme? What did you change it to? Can you add the error log?

Comment: I mean changing the theme Add this theme:
<Style name = "AppColor" parent = "Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
 <! - Customize your theme here. ->
 <Item name = "colorPrimary"> @ color / colorPrimary </ item>
 <Item name = "colorPrimaryDark"> @ color / colorPrimaryDark </ item>
 <Item name = "colorAccent"> @ color / colorAccent </ item>
 </ Style>
Through the Android Manifest the application tells "This app has been disabled", you can see the application form through the link at the top. Please help!!